# Can't replace dictionary key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am confused as to why the dictionary key `45.0` isn't getting replaced in `cmd_gear.states()` but it is in `dictionary`:

```
print 'original cmd_gear.states() = '
pprint.pprint(cmd_gear.states())

cmd_gear.states()['N'] = cmd_gear.states()[45.0]
del cmd_gear.states()[45.0]

print '\nreplaced cmd_gear.states() = '
pprint.pprint(cmd_gear.states())

dictionary = {
6.0: [[288.031, 441.971]],
45.0: [[0.211, 6.071], [34.101, 69.671], [540.021, 644.761]]}
dictionary['N'] = dictionary[45.0]
del dictionary[45.0]
print '\nreplaced dictionary'
pprint.pprint(dictionary)
```

Here is the output:

```
original cmd_gear.states() = 
{
 6.0: [[288.031, 441.971]],
 45.0: [[0.211, 6.071], [34.101, 69.671], [540.021, 644.761]]}

replaced cmd_gear.states() = 
{
 6.0: [[288.031, 441.971]],
 45.0: [[0.211, 6.071], [34.101, 69.671], [540.021, 644.761]]} # this is what confuses me!!! 45.0 should be 'N'

replaced dictionary
{
 6.0: [[288.031, 441.971]],
 'N': [[0.211, 6.071], [34.101, 69.671], [540.021, 644.761]]}
```

I am really confused as to why it won't replace 45.0 with N.

Comment: Could you produce a more minimal example?

Comment: Ok. I will modify my code.

Comment: Please show the definition of `cmd_gear.states()`.

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal modified

Comment: Is `cmd_gear.states()` returning a reference to the same dictionary each time, or does it create a new dictionary to return each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @chepner, the problem was, I was getting a new dictionary returned each time. You must make a variable equal to `cmd_gear.states()` otherwise you will not be able to modify it. Here is the solution:

```
cmd_gear_states = cmd_gear.states()
print 'original cmd_gear_states = '
pprint.pprint(cmd_gear_states)

cmd_gear_states['N'] = cmd_gear_states[45.0]
del cmd_gear_states[45.0]

print '\nreplaced cmd_gear_states = '
pprint.pprint(cmd_gear_states)
```